# SharePoint 2016: filter on managed metadata column with AND operator

Tags: document-library, column, filter, managed-metadata

We are using SharePoint 2016 and have a document library with a multiple managed metadata column. In this document library we try sometimes to filter on this column. We can select 1 or more terms in this filter. Now it is filtering with the OR operator. Is it possible to filter with the AND operator?